# Entity Component System: Dependency Between Systems

Tags: c#, architecture, component-based, entity-component-system

Inspired by the [Entity Component System Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system), I started to refactor my 2D tiled-based game to follow the rule "favor composition over inheritance".

However, after writing the movement related components and system, I wasn't sure how to continue and implement the AIControllerSystem:

On one hand, I want to decuple as much as I can the MovementSystem and AIControllerSystem, and on the other hand I want to be able to send a movement action from AIControllerSystem to MovementSystem so I won't need to reimplement the movement logic.

Currently, my movement code looks like this:

```
public class PositionComponent : IComponent
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public Direction FacingDirection { get; set; }
}

public class MovementComponent : IComponent
{
    public int Speed { get; set; }
    public Direction Direction { get; set; }
    public bool IsMoving { get; set; }
    public byte OffsetInTile { get; set; }
}

public class MovementSystem : ISystem
{
    private long _timer;

    // states the behavior depends on
    private PositionComponent _positionComponent;
    private MovementComponent _movementComponent;

    public MovementSystem(PositionComponent positionComponent, MovementComponent movementComponent)
    {
        this._positionComponent = positionComponent;
        this._movementComponent = movementComponent;
        this._timer = 0;
    }
    public void Update(long elapsedTime)
    {
        // some logic
    }
    
    public bool CanMove(Direction moveDirection)
    {
        return !this._movementComponent.IsMoving;
    }
    
    public void Move(Direction moveDirection, bool updateFacing=true)
    {
        if (this.CanMove())
        {
            this._timer = 0;
            this._movementComponent.IsMoving = true;
            this._movementComponent.Direction = moveDirection;
            if (updateFacing)
                this._positionComponent.FacingDirection = moveDirection;
        }
    }
}
```

**My Approach**

I thought about several ways to handle the AIControllerSystem->MovementSystem dependency:

1. Let the AIControllerSystem hold a reference to the MovementSystem, and send messages via a simple method call.
2. Let the AIControllerSystem send messages to the MovementSystem via a message queue.
3. Declare interface *IMovable* for movable game objects, and let the AIControllerSystem hold a reference   to such interface.
4. Sticking to the ECS architecture, expose the MovementComponent and PositionComponent to the AIControllerSystem, and "communicate" through them.

Personaly, I think options 3 and 4 are better, although option 4 may lead to code duplications (e.g. check if move is valid, unless the MovementComponent will be changed).

Option 3 will allow me to add game objects like the following:

```
public class Player : IMovable
{
    // states
    MovementComponent _movementComponent;
    PositionComponent _positionComponent;
    
    // behaviors
    MovementSystem _movementSystem
    
    
    //...
}

public class NPC : IMovable, IAIControllable
{
    // states
    MovementComponent _movementComponent;
    PositionComponent _positionComponent;
    
    // behaviors
    MovementSystem _movementSystem
    AIControllerSystem _aiControllerSystem // will be dependent on the NPC
    
    //...
}
```

I know my design is not "pure" ECS or even close to, but I think this hybrid approach is pretty modular to easily perform changes and add game objects with unique behavior combinations.

What do you think?

Thanks.

**Edit**

Some clarifications:

- The MovementSystem is responsible for updating position (old tile -> neighbor tile) based on Speed, while the OffsetInTile represent a fixed point current movement progress (0-255).
- For now, the AIControllerSystem is responsible for the movement "thinking" and operating of non-player entities (like NPCs).
- The problem in short: keeping the described systems decupled, while letting the AIControllerSystem to communicate with the MovementSystem to perform movement actions.

Comment: I am not sure what your question/problem is? What is it your movement system does? What is it your AI system does? Why do they clash / need to interact? While there's no black and white approach to implementing things, a system should generally do as granular a task as possible. E.g. a MovementSystem decides what the new position of an Entity is based on the current Position component and Speed component...

Comment: @dot_Sp0T added additional information in my question.